# Bash automatically creating () and ()! files

Tags: macos, terminal, bash

I noticed that the Yosemite system has been creating files with names just "()" and "()!" in places where I recently made bash commands and want to know why. I can't even delete them use rm as after I press enter the cursor just moves to the next line like a unfinished command. I tried google but I guess the keywords () is too general to give me back a meaningful answer.

Comment: I have bash running every second (via `cron`) and certainly never had those files. You must be doing things wrong yourself.

Comment: And of course you can't do `rm ()`. You need to do `rm '()'` instead. `rm ()` begins a function definition.

Answer (score 1):

Bash, by itself, will not create files like this. These files are probably created by you accidentally through incorrect typing/pasting of commands.

You can remove the files using rm:

```
rm '()' '()!'
```